# Change the design of the ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to change the design of the Windows Forms `ComboBox` to this:
[image]

Do I need to redesign the button and inherit from `UserControl`, and start all the functionality from zero?

Or enough to inherit from `ComboBox`, and just what I need to do is change the graphics?
 And if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use winforms? In .NET's [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) it is much easier to change the style of combo boxes (and other controls). You can find numerous [tutorials](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/2/20/customizing-wpf-combo-box-style) and/or [examples](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-combobox/) on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to inherit from the `ComboBox` and override only the painting functionality.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // your drawing comes code here
}
```

The parameter gives you a [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) instance through which you can draw anything you like. Lines, arcs, images even. I don't know the exact definition of the graphics you showed, so try to find out how to draw it.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give me some guidance?

Comment: I've added some detail. Experiment a bit. And the internet is full of examples to similar tasks.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The ComboBox does not call the OnPaint event.  It's a wrapper to the ancient WIN32 controls.  It's hard to paint a working text box.